# How to save data on SD card in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to save data on device in external storage (physical SD card) in react native.

I've tried react-native-fs plugin but it does not allow me to save data on SD card.

When i used RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath as per this plugin's documentation then it showed me path like "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files"

So is there a way to achieve the same using this plugin or any other plugin.

Custom code solutions are also welcomed.

**Solution needs to work for both Android and iOS devices.**

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you give permission write external storage?

Comment: Yes, I've added permissions for Android for now in AndroidManifest.xml as follows:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />                                               
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: no one answered this question, :-(